# Using a vector of logical expressions to subset dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to use a vector of logical expressions to subset a data frame. As a simple example, here is a data frame that I will subset using a logical expression. First, I'll type in the logical expression manually:

```
> dat <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,1), y = c(0,0,0,1), z = c(0,1,1,1))
> dat
  x y z
1 0 0 0
2 0 0 1
3 1 0 1
4 1 1 1
> subset(dat, x == 1)
  x y z
3 1 0 1
4 1 1 1
```

If I have a vector of logical expressions, how can I call from that vector and apply them to a subsetting method? Here is one way that doesn't work:

```
> criteria <- as.factor(c("x == 1", "y == 1", "y == 1 & z == 1"))
> subset(dat, criteria[1])
Error in subset.data.frame(dat, criteria[1]) : 'subset' must be logical
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide an example of exactly what you want output to look like? Having a hard time understanding exactly what you are trying to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `parse` and `eval` to evaluate the condition as a vector of string.

```
criteria <- c("x == 1", "y == 1", "y == 1 & z == 1")

subset(dat, eval(parse(text = criteria)))
#   x y z
# 4 1 1 1
```

We can use index to select the element in the `criteria` vector to subset the data frame.

```
subset(dat, eval(parse(text = criteria[1])))
#   x y z
# 3 1 0 1
# 4 1 1 1
```

Comment: I bet this is what OP is looking for

Comment: This is possible, but not a sort of code that should be encouraged under normal circumstances.

Comment: A slightly better way if evaluation needs to be delayed is to store expressions instead of strings: `criteria <- list(quote(x == 1), quote(y == 1), quote(y == 1 & z == 1)); lapply(criteria, function(c) subset(dat, eval(c)))` That way syntax errors will be caught earlier instead of causing headaches far from where they originated.

Comment: We can also evaluate criteria separately with `eval(parse(text=as.character(criteria[1])),envir = dat)`, and filter afterward.

Comment: @allistaire and then `subset(dat, eval(criteria[[1]]))` right ? Can we get from OP's character vector to  your quote vector ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper `lapply(criteria, function(c) parse(text = c))` is simplest, though there's a difference in the class of language object returned

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Another option is `rlang::parse_exprs` `expr <- c("x == 1", "y == 1", "y == 1 & z == 1");dat %>% filter(!!! parse_exprs(paste(expr, collapse=";")))`

Answer (score 3):

You can't make an atomic vector of vectors, so you can contain them in a list. Subsetting with `[`, which is easier to program with than `subset`,

```r
dat <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,1), 
                  y = c(0,0,0,1), 
                  z = c(0,1,1,1))

indices <- list(dat$x == 1, 
                dat$y == 1, 
                dat$x == 1 & dat$z == 1)

str(indices)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : logi [1:4] FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#>  $ : logi [1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#>  $ : logi [1:4] FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE

dat[indices[[1]], ]
#>   x y z
#> 3 1 0 1
#> 4 1 1 1

lapply(indices, function(i) dat[i, ])
#> [[1]]
#>   x y z
#> 3 1 0 1
#> 4 1 1 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   x y z
#> 4 1 1 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   x y z
#> 3 1 0 1
#> 4 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

With a vector of logicals:

```
critearia <- dat$x == 1 & dat$y == 1 & dat$z == 1
subset(dat, critearia)
```

Directly:

```
subset(dat, x == 1 & y == 1 & z == 1)
```

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dat  <- as.data.table(dat)
dat[x == 1 & y == 1 & z == 1]
```